# Replace a placholder in a file with git commit short sha

Tags: bash, git, sed, gitlab-ci, odt

I have in a file a placeholder `GitHash` and want to replace this with the git commit short sha hash and use [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) for example.

This should be done in a pipeline job in GitLab.

So I wrote following into my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
set-revesion:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  stage: Set
  script: 
    - apk update
    - apk add zip # Because it is a .odt which needs to be unpacked
    - mkdir MyFile
    - unzip MyFile.odt -d unpack
    - cd unpack
    - sed -e 's|GitHash|${$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}|g' -i content.xml
    - sed -e 's|GitHash|${$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}|g' -i styles.xml
    - zip -r ../MyFile/MyFile.odt .
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - Specification/
```

Comment: What is the question? Suppose your `sed` commands succeed, what next?

Comment: sed replace `GitHash` with `$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA`.

Comment: I want to let `$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA` be the sha short of the last commit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbash%5D+difference+quotes

Comment: @N0cynym You need double quotes: `sed -e "s|GitHash|${$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}|g" -i content.xml` instead of single (apostrophes).

Comment: This works correctly: `- sed -e "s|GitHash|$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA|g" -i content.xml`